# Finding the sum of non-zero individual values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

So I wrote this code, I am trying to find the sum of each non-zero rating of each book, in order to find the average of the ratings of each book, without including the zero ratings of each book.

This is what I have tried to do, it is working. But I couldn't figure out how to find the sum of each rating of each book and to find the average.

```
books = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
biglist = [{'user1' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : -2, 'book3' : 3}}, 
            {'user2' : {'book1' : 5, 'book2' : 0, 'book3' : -3}}, 
            {'user3' : {'book1' : 1, 'book2' : 5, 'book3' : 3}}] 


total = dict() 
count = 0
for list_item in biglist: 
    for key, value in list_item.items(): 
        for key2, value2 in value.items():
            total[key2] = value2 + total.get(key2,0)
            for book in books:
                if value2 != 0 and book == key2:
                        count += 1
                        print(f"Found non-zero value, [{key2} : {value2}]
```

Comment: use filters to remove the zeros.. then just do an average using counts on the remaining... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/

Comment: that's what I have been trying to do for 4 hours....

Comment: Your data structure is complex. Look to reduce the complexity by using filter to remove books with zeros. Then map them into a flat list using the map command and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that should work with your datastructure. Collect all ratings, and then filter the individual lists.

```
big_dict = {}
for book in books:
    big_dict[book] = []

# collect all ratings
for d in biglist:
    for _, ratings in d.items():
        for book in books:
            big_dict[book].append(ratings.get(book))

for book, rating in big_dict.items():
    # compute averages of filtered list
    average_rating = np.mean([a for a in rating if a != 0])
    print(book, average_rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

```
books = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
biglist = [{'user1' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : -2, 'book3' : 3}}, 
            {'user2' : {'book1' : 5, 'book2' : 0, 'book3' : -3}}, 
            {'user3' : {'book1' : 1, 'book2' : 5, 'book3' : 3}}]
```

Considering you want to calculate average and sum if ratings, here is a neat solution:

All ratings: `ratings={book:[biglist[i]['user'+str(i+1)][book] for i, _ in enumerate(biglist)] for book in books}`

This outputs: `{'book1': [0, 5, 1], 'book2': [-2, 0, 5], 'book3': [3, -3, 3]}`

.

Sum of ratings: `sum_of_ratings = {book:sum(ratings[book]) for book in books}`

This outputs: `{'book1': 6, 'book2': 3, 'book3': 3}`

.

Avg of ratings: `avg_of_ratings =  {book:sum_of_ratings[book]/len(ratings[book]) for book in books}`

This outputs: `{'book1': 2.0, 'book2': 1.0, 'book3': 1.0}`

.

Avg of non-zero ratings: `avg_of_non_zero_ratings =  {book:sum_of_ratings[book]/sum([i!=0 for i in ratings[book]]) for book in books}`

This outputs: `{'book1': 3.0, 'book2': 1.5, 'book3': 1.0}`